# how to lose bum fat

Tags: weight-loss, burn-fat

I am 14 and four months ago i was 80kg, and i realised that i needed to lose weight so i went on the folowig diet:

Breakfast: semi-skimmed milk with the cereal of my choice (1 bowl)

break: apple

Lunch:3-4 whole-grain crackers

Break: two tangerines

Dinner: whatever my mum made but with no carbs e.g. spaghetti bolognese -> bolognese and lettuce and so on.

Every other night i would do a 5k jog

and this repeated and i have now lost 12kg but now i am doing the same diet but i cant lose any more weight. my waistline is fine, but all of the remaining fat is in my bum, what is the best/fastest way to get rid of it?

Comment: You can't spot reduce. It sounds like you've lost enough to be pretty small already, what would you say you body fat percentage is? If it's already low, it may be an issue of building muscle to fill you butt out instead of losing more fat.

Comment: How do you know that all your fat is in your bum? It could be a postural issue.

Comment: You can't lose fat from a certain area, but you can put muscle on that area.  More muscle extends the skin and subcutaneous fat, making the area tighter and less flabby.  You could try doing some squats and deadlifts to put some muscle on your glutes.  Glutes, by the way, are the largest muscle in the body, possibly the most important, and probably the easiest to build.

Answer (score 4):

At 14 your body is still growing and your hormone levels are shifting around. I know people who grew 0.5 meters from the time they graduated high school until they graduated college. We have an image obsessed culture but try not to think that you need to have any particularly perfect body image at the age of 14.

It sounds like you have your diet fairly well understood: consider tracking your calories on a site like dailyburn.com (or myfitnesspal; there are others). Diet has the largest impact on your body fat.

As your body fat drops, your body gets more insulin sensitive and you store fat more efficiently. It's much easier to go from 25% to 20% body fat than it is from 15% to 10%: the lower you go the more your body is going to fight you because from an evolutionary standpoint it's not good to have such little reserve energy.

Stay active and get into a good strength training program like starting strength or stronglifts 5x5. A good diet, an active lifestyle, and strength training will pop you into the top 1% of fitness relatively quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe what you're dissatisfied with more specifically? That diet seems close to anorectic, especially with a 5k jog every day and the fact that your body is still developing at a very rapid pace, or should be.

Most people will never have perfect bodies, there will always be things we're dissatisfied about, not matter how much fat you get rid of and no matter how much you jog. Also, most people will judge you by your positive sides, not by the negative ones, this includes your peers.

If you really have to do something, I would consider building a bit of muscle, it will make you look a bit firmer and will also be healthy and practical to have. That's a much better approach to looking good than starving yourself. You might want to consider consulting a professional dietitian instead of asking random internet people.